# Sorting parents and childs using Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have an "Item" class that contains the following fields (in short): id (related to the primary key of the Item table on SQL Server), description, sequence (non-null integer), and link (a reference to the id of the parent object), can be null)

I would like to sort by using Java as follows:

```
Id    Sequence   Link    Description
1     1          null    Item A
99    ..1        1       Son of A, first of the sequence
57    ..2        1       Son of A, second of the sequence
66    ..3        1       Son of A, third of the sequence
2     2          null    Item B
3     3          null    Item C
...
```

(I put the dots for better visualization)

That is, I would like the children of a certain item to come directly below their parent, ordered by the "sequence" field.

I tried using the comparator, but it failed:

```
public class SequenceComparator implements Comparator<Item> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        String x1 = o1.getSequence().toString();
        String x2 = o2.getSequence().toString();
        int sComp = x1.compareTo(x2);

        if (sComp != 0) {
            return sComp;
        } else {
            x1 = o1.getLink().toString();
            x2 = o2.getLink() == null?"":o2.getLink().toString();
            return x1.compareTo(x2);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you directly sort it in SQL? This would be way easier, in fact, as you are trying to sort items on numerals

Comment: This is a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). You're looking for [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: I need to do this in Java. It is not my decision

Comment: You are giving a lot of details about irrelevant fields, but not about the single field that matters: Sequence. How does it look exactly, what do the dots stand for?

Comment: I figure the dots are just for visual representation. I don't see other irrelevant information except that it's SQL based

Comment: Have you got parents and children only, that is, two levels? Or could there be grandchildren, grandgrandchildren, …?

Comment: Just one level, like the example shows

Answer (score 0):

Considering your data structure is a Tree (with `null` as the root node) with no cycles:

You have to walk up the tree for both `o1` and `o2` until you find a common ancestor. Once you do, take one step back along both branches to find their relative order (with `Sequence`)

Finding the common ancestor <s>may be tricky to do, and I don't know if it</s> is possible in linear time, <s>but certainly possible in O(n log n) time</s> (with n the length of the branches)

Comment: The asker said in a comment, “Just one level, like the example shows”. If there were multiple levels, this would be a very fine approach.

Comment: I think you could find the common ancestor in linear time when you know all paths end in the `null` root. For example, first count the length of each path up to the root. Starting over from the leaves, first count appropriate number of steps up the longer path so you’re on the same level. Then it’s a matter of pairwise comparison until you meet the common ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

New answer: I don’t think you want one comparator to control the complete sorting, because when sorting children you need the sequence of the parent, and you don’t have an easy or natural access to that from within the comparator.

Instead I suggest a sorting in a number of steps:

1. Put the items into groups by parent items. So one group will be the item with id 1 and all its children. Items with no children will be in a group on their own.
2. Sort each group so the parent comes first and then all the children in the right order.
3. Sort the groups by the parent’s sequence.
4. Concatenate the sorted groups into one list.

Like this, using both Java 8 streams and `List.sort()`:

```
    // group by parent id
    Map<Integer, List<Item>> intermediate = input.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.getLink() == null ? Integer.valueOf(i.getId()) : i.getLink()));

    // sort each inner list so that parent comes first and then children by sequence
    for (List<Item> innerList : intermediate.values()) {
        innerList.sort((i1, i2) -> {
            if (i1.getLink() == null) { // i1 is parent
                return -1; // parent first
            }
            if (i2.getLink() == null) {
                return 1;
            }
            return i1.getSequence().compareTo(i2.getSequence());
        });
    }

    // sort lists by parent’s sequence, that is, sequence of first item
    List<Item> result = intermediate.values().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(innerList -> innerList.get(0).getSequence()))
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The output is (leaving out the item description):

```
 1 1   null
99 ..1 1
57 ..2 1
66 ..3 1
 2 2   null
 3 3   null
```

(This output was produced with a `toString` method that printed the dots when converting an item with a parent to a `String`.)

If you cannot use Java 8, I still believe the general idea of the steps mentioned above will work, only some of the steps will require a little more code.

I deleted my previous answer since I had misunderstood the part about what `getLink()` returns and then decided that that answer wasn’t worth trying to salvage.

Edit:

I am actually ignoring this piece from the documentation of `Collectors.groupingBy()`: “There are no guarantees on the …, mutability, of the … `List` objects returned.” It still works with my Java 8. If immutability of the list should prevent sorting, the solution is to create a new `ArrayList` containing the same items.

With thanks to Stuart Marks for the inspiration, the comparator for sorting the inner lists needs not be as clumsy as above. The sorting can be written in this condensed way:

```
        innerList.sort(Comparator.comparing(itm -> itm.getLink() == null ? null : itm.getSequence(),
                Comparator.nullsFirst(Integer::compare)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that there are only two layers in the hierarchy, this boils down to a classic multi-level sort. There are two kinds of items, parents and children, distinguished by whether the `link` field is null. The trick is that the sorting at each level isn't on a particular field. Instead, the value on which to sort on depends on what kind of item it is.

The first level of sorting should be on the parent value. The parent value of a parent item is its sequence, but the parent value of a child item is the sequence of the parent it's linked to. Child items are linked to parent items via their id, so the first thing we need to do is to build up a map from ids to sequence values of parent nodes:

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> idSeqMap =
        list.stream()
            .filter(it -> it.getLink() == null)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getId, Item::getSequence));
```

(This assumes that ids are unique, which is reasonable as they're related to the table primary key.)

Now that we have this map, you can write a lambda expression that gets the appropriate parent value from the item. (This assumes that all non-null link values point to existing items.) This is as follows:

```
(Item it) -> it.getLink() == null ? it.getSequence() : idSeqMap.get(it.getLink())
```

The second level of sorting should be on the child value. The child value of a parent item is null, so nulls will need to be sorted before any non-null value. The child value of a child item is its sequence. A lambda expression for getting the child value is:

```
(Item it) -> it.getLink() == null ? null : it.getSequence()
```

Now, we can combine these using the `Comparator` helper functions introduced in Java 8. The result can be passed directly to the `List.sort()` method.

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((Item it) -> it.getLink() == null ? it.getSequence() : idSeqMap.get(it.getLink()))
                    .thenComparing((Item it) -> it.getLink() == null ? null : it.getSequence(),
                                   Comparator.nullsFirst(Integer::compare))
                    .thenComparingInt(Item::getId));
```

The first level of sorting is pretty straightforward; just pass the first lambda expression (which extracts the parent value) to `Comparator.comparingInt`.

The second level of sorting is a bit tricky. I'm assuming the result of `getLink()` is a nullable `Integer`. First, we have to extract the child value using the second lambda expression. This results in a nullable value, so if we were to pass this to `thenComparing` we'd get a `NullPointerException`. Instead, `thenComparing` allows us to pass a secondary comparator. We'll use this to handle nulls. For this secondary comparator we pass

```
    Comparator.nullsFirst(Integer::compare)
```

This compares `Integer` objects, with nulls sorted first, and non-nulls compared in turn using the `Integer.compare` method.

Finally, we compare id values as a last resort. This is optional if you're using this comparator only for sorting; duplicates will end up next to each other. But if you use this comparator for a `TreeSet`, you'll want to make sure that different items never compare equals. Presumably a database id value would be sufficient to differentiate all unique items.

Comment: Are you assuming that for parents the sequence coincides with the id? While in the example data provided that holds true, only the original asker can tell whether it always does.

Comment: @OleV.V. Oh yes, good point. I was assuming that non-null link values are in the same value space as sequence numbers. But rereading the question carefully I see the O.P. says the link is the **id** of the parent not the sequence of the parent. This could be handled by building a map from from ids to sequences of parent objects, and then looking in this map in the first lambda when the link value is used. I guess we should wait for the O.P. to answer.

Comment: @OleV.V. I went ahead and retrofitted the code along the lines I described above. It was pretty simple, and it didn't make sense to wait for the O.P. to respond, since it's not clear from the comments that we're waiting for him.